# Windows API Textfield with offset characters

Tags: windows, winapi, textfield

Is it possible using the Windows API, to create a textfield that lets me offset characters by exact pixels? if so - how?

for example, I would like to place two O letters on top of each other, such that they form something like an 8 ?

context is an application for a language where most of the glyphs are written left to right, but sometimes some of the glyphs are stacket on top of each other.

Windows API because the framework we're using already uses the Windows API for the whole GUI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use superclassing or subclassing and draw the text yourself using GDI functions

Comment: we currently draw the text ourself that way, but it's much slower than a regular textfield